# return type of a generic object creation method

Tags: java, class, generics, reflection

I want to make a method which takes a class name as an argument and returns an object of that class, my current implementation returns a type of `Object` which is casted to the correct type when needed. My question is, can I implement this with a generic method? Like... give the class name and directly return an instance of it?

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: How would you derive the correct generic type from a class's *name*, i.e. convert a `String` to a generic `T`? Surely, you can do an unchecked cast, but that doesn't really improve over your current manual cast.

Comment: @fadytaher Will all your possible classes have a 0-arg constructor?

Comment: @RohitJain I guess I can do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to create an instance with a specific (non-default) constuctor, then you can do:

```
public <T> T createInstanceFrom(Class<T> clazz, Class<?> ... params) {
    Constructor<T> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(params);
    T result = constructor.newInstance();
    return result;
}
```

Note that you will have to handle several possible exceptions here.

But, if you just need an instance, which can be aquired by the default class constructor, then you can do:

```
return clazz.newInstance();
```

Comment: That type cast is not needed. And your code can be replaced with just `clazz.newInstance()`

Comment: @kocko hmmm bare with me please , say I have a class called Part , how employ the createInstanceFrom(); now ?

Comment: Just use the provided method with : `Part intastance = createInstanceFrom(Part.class);` or `Part instance = Part.class.newInstance();`

Answer (score 2):

Use *reflection:*

```
<your instance> = (<your type>)Class.forName(<your class name>).getDeclaredConstructor(<your constructor parameters>).newInstance(<those constructor parameters>);
```

Of course, you're relying on all your constructors having the same parameters. This can be enforced by appropriate unit testing.

Comment: okey but if this statement is in a function , what return type of the function should be ?

Comment: @fadytaher: use generics in that case: see kocko's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public static <T> T cst(Class<? extends T> clazz)
{
    try 
    {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
    catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T>T  getInstance(Class<T> type)
            throws Exception {
        return type.newInstance();

    }
```